# fetch data from api into redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using React and  trying to fetch data from my api into redux by initialising my `fetchProducts` function when the component Mounts.

The problem is it seems to dispatch the `GET_PRODUCTS_REQUEST` action but doesn't get past this so no data is being loaded into redux.

going to `http://localhost:3000/product` I can see the data so this is correct

How can I load the data into my redux reducer?

**component.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
      this.props.fetchProducts()
    }
```

**actions.js**

```
export function fetchProducts() {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchProductsRequest());
        const { error, response } = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/products');
        if (response) {
        dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(response.data));
        //This is required only if you want to do something at component level
        return true;
        } else if (error) {
        dispatch(getDataFailure(error));
        //This is required only if you want to do something at component level
        return false;
        }
    };
}

export const fetchProductsRequest = () => ({
  type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST
});

export const fetchProductsSuccess = products => ({
  type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
  payload: { products }
});

export const fetchProductsFailure = error => ({
  type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE,
  payload: { error }
});
```

**productsReducer.js**

```
import {
    FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST,
    FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE
  } from '../../Constants'

  const initialState = {
    items: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null
  };

  export default function productReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: true,
          error: null
        };

      case FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          items: action.payload.products
        };

      case FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: action.payload.error,
          items: []
        };

      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

Comment: For async actions, it is advised to use [the redux-thunk package](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) as described in the official redux docs.

Comment: I have this in my app

Answer (score 0):

```
export function fetchProducts() {
return(dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchProductsRequest());
    return fetch('http://localhost:3000/products')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(response.data));
      return json.products;
    })
};}
```

Try call default method `then` for catch response in u async fetch

Comment: this also doesn't get past the request

Comment: If edit this  
`export const fetchProductsSuccess = products => ({
  type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
  payload: { products }
});`  
on this  
`export const fetchProductsSuccess = products => ({
  type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
  payload: products 
});`
What have results ?

Comment: Same try inspect what happens when u set state in redux (logs in console)
`store.subscribe(() => {
  store.getState();
  console.log(store.getState());
});`

Comment: this works but I want to add an action before the request and not sure hwo this can be done`export function fetchProducts() {
  return dispatch =>
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3000/products`)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS, payload: response.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE, payload: response.data });
      });
}`

Comment: its my work response). I dispatch isLoading action before request
`export const loadData = (page) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(isLoading(true));

    api.get(`pages/${page}`)
        .then(response => {
          dispatch(getPageSuccess(response.data));
          dispatch(isLoading(false));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          // dispatch(getPageError(err))
        })
  }
};
`
My isLoading action 
`export const isLoading = (bool) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_PAGE_LOADING,
    isLoading: bool,
  };
};`